# sqlite вычитание дат

Tags: sqlite, дата

есть база с датами в виде 03.12.2005
как выбрать строки в возрастном промежутке например от 10 до 20 лет?

Comment: От 10 лет до 20 считая с какого момента? Считая с начальной даты, считая  с сегодняшнего дня, или как? У вас там в `date` или в строках хранится дата?

Comment: @AntonSorokin нужно выбрать на сегодняшний день сколько лет прошло с указанной даты